# Label invertida stacked Bar R

Tags: ggplot2, r, gráfico, label

As cores pros generos feminino/masculino aparecem corretamente no grafico, porém, quando adiciono "labels" a quantidade que é do gen F aparece embaixo e do gen M aparece no meio

```
p4 <- ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(y = QTD, x = SINTOMA, fill = GENERO), data = charts.data,
                           stat="identity") + theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = 1), 
    plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 1), 
    legend.title = element_text(face = "italic"), 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray91"), 
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gainsboro"), 
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "gray75"), 
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "gray72")) + theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(family = "mono", 
    size = 11, face = "bold.italic", colour = "gray2", 
    hjust = 0.5), plot.caption = element_text(size = 10, 
    hjust = 0)) +labs(subtitle = "Frequencia de Sintomas por Genero")
```

acredito que o **ERRO** está no trecho a seguir :

```
p4 <- p4 + geom_text(data=charts.data, aes(x = SINTOMA, y = QTD,
                     label = paste0(QTD,"")), size=4)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem pode me ajudar, pfv?

Comment: 1) Ponha a base `charts.data`, e o `mapping = aes(etc)` na chamada a `ggplot()` e retire de `geom_bar`. 2) Se já tem a base `charts.data`, e o `mapping = aes(etc)`, ***não repita*** na `geom_text`. 3) `geom_text(size = 4, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))`.

Comment: **Nota:** um erro frequente no `ggplot` é repetir os dados e `aes()`. Se forem comuns às `geom_*` ponha sempre na chamada original a `ggplot`, o argument `inherit.aes = TRUE` é o defeito, o que simplifica muito o código e torna os resultados mais consistentes com os dados. Estabelece logo desde o início os elementos usados nas várias layers do gráfico.